# Qt: Ambiguous shortcut issue

Tags: qt, shortcut, qtextedit, ambiguous

I've implemented a dialog with two customized text-editor inside(Two editor objects with same class)
This custom widget is an inherited class from QWidget and it has two widgets inside, one is a actions-tool-bar and second is a QTextEdit. I set some shortcuts to this custom widget for some actions like 'Make text Bold', 'Make text Italic', so on.

here is a picture of these widgets inside of my dialog:

[image: Two custom Text-Edit inside a dialog]

So far every thing is ok.
But, when I press Ctrl+B for example, I got this error message:

```
QAction::eventFilter: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Ctrl+B
```

setting the shortcut context to WidgetWithChildrenShortcut won't help me to disambiguate shortcuts.

anyone has any other idea?

Comment: is it just for Ctrl + B? Did you try it on italic (ctrl + i)?

Comment: all shortcuts doesn't work. even ctrl+I(Something strange in ctrl+I is that one indent the text I think that one is another issue!)

Comment: it seems you define same shortcuts twice or more in your projects, in different parts

Comment: It solved! you can find my implementation at this address: https://github.com/m-o-s-t-a-f-a/dana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. My editor was inherited from qtextedit. I add this lines to each action, and it works now!

```
void MyEditor::addActionToToolbar(QAction *a)
{
    a->setShortcutContext(Qt::WidgetWithChildrenShortcut);
    addAction(a);

    QToolButton* btn = new QToolButton(this);
    btn->setDefaultAction( a );
    btn->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    btn->setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed );
    btn->setIconSize(QSize(16,16));

    toolBar->addWidget(btn);    
}
```

Comment: The important part here is the call QWidget::AddAction and  QAction::setShortcutContext(Qt::WidgetWithChildrenShortcut);

Answer (score 1):

You can have two toolbars, but they should use an action that acts on the currently focused editor, and you want only one QAction to exist, not multiple of them. In spite of one QAction you can have multiple buttons linked to it.

Most likely your editor widgets behave inappropriately by defining their own actions. They shouldn't do that.

Comment: So what's your solution? forget my implementation and my design. There is a dialog with two rich-text-editor( it could be anything else) and each editor has own actions, you want to define the shortcuts for them without conflict...

Answer (score 0):

you need to [install an event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter), there is a nice example in documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, dare. I did it but it's a bit messy code. I'm looking for something else.